# What happened to the other Eternian Astrisk Users?

Tags: bravely-second

In *Bravely Second* while you end up meeting with most of the Eternian Astrisk Users, seeing what happened to them years after the events of the previous game.

However i have noticed some of them are missing mainly

- Vincent S. Court - The Spirit Master
- Victoria F. Stein - The Anarchist
- Sage Yulyana - The Conjuour
- Lester DeRosso - The Vampire
- Doctor Qada - The Salve-Maker

Now on the one hand Lester DeRosso may no longer exists because he gave up his life to stop Lord Ouroboros's regeneration however there is only 1 Lord Ouroboros and there are multiple Luxendarc which means only 1 Lester DeRosso sacrificed himself.

With Sage Yulyana in a sidequest in *Bravely Second* if you side with Mephilia Venus and defeat Nobutsuna Kamiizumi she says something about how Sage Yulyana may no longer be of the world after fighting a Ba'al (i assume it was Diamante) however it is hinted that it was Sage Yulyana who told Ominus Crow about Femto Flare being a weapon to stop a Ba'al and in the past no one knew about Ba'als until Diamante decimated the moon and crashed on Luxendarc

So i am wondering what has happened to the other Eternian Astrisk Users<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1: to be honest i could give a crap about Doctor Qada but for completion sake i have added him</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Unmarked spoilers for *Bravely Default* and *Bravely Second* below.**

Not accounting for the alternate reality versions, of which there are several for each character, this is the status of each of the listed characters by the time of *Bravely Second*:

- **Victor S. Court** - [killed by the party](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Victor_S._Court) in Eternian Central Command back in *Bravely Default* (you listed Vincent S. Court, which is actually Victor's father. Vincent was [killed by Victoria](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Vincent_S._Court) before the events of *Bravely Default*)
- **Victoria F. Stein** - [killed by the party](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_F._Stein) in Eternian Central Command back in *Bravely Default*, along with Victor.
- **Sage Yulyana** - [killed in the battle with the Ba'al, Diamante](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Yulyana). He managed to seal Diamante into the Kustra Archipelago before he died.
- **Lester DeRosso** - [disappeared from Luxendarc](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Lester_DeRosso). This one is slightly more vague. The DeRosso we see sacrifice himself against Ouroboros in *Bravely Default* is the one from that "final world" and not from the original world that the characters originate from. After the events of *Bravely Default*, the original DeRosso helped Yulyana hide the weapons that Yulyana had previously stolen from the Crystal Orthodoxy (the OP weapons in the blue chests, if you played the game) in small pocket dimensions under [Centro Keep](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ruins_of_Centro_Keep) and [Mount Karka](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Underflow). He vanished after that, no longer being found in Vampire Castle (occupied by [Yōko](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Y%C5%8Dko_(Bravely_Second))) nor anywhere else in Luxendarc.
- **Qada** - [killed by Kamiizumi](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Qada). He intended to overthrow the Duchy after being defeated by the party in *Bravely Default*, but was overheard and struck down by Kamiizumi. According to the wiki, his ghost remained there, and was unaware that he had been killed.

Answer (score 0):

Qada and the V's are dead, plain and simple. The V's are a storyline fight and canonically die, Qada's canon ending seems to be the one where you fight him before Kamiizumi, when he kills the alchemist after his fake death trick.

Yulyana is mentioned to have battled Diamante and then vanished, but it's possible he may have either died, hid himself for some reason(maybe recover his strength), or ascended to the plane Yoko mentioned in the castle.

Meanwhile DeRosso is mentioned to be alive in the bestiary entry for the bats you battle in the castle he lived in, but nothing more. Given we see another version of him post-Ouroboros and that only W-0 DeRosso sacrificed himself, he's probably alive but wasn't brought in for not having his asterisk available.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide some sources for this.